# Why is my connection string property not available on the My.Settings object?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have created a .settings file and added a connection string setting called *InvoiceConnection*, yet this does not appear in the Intellisense for the `My.Settings` object. Why is this?

Comment: Did you build the project after creating the setting?

Comment: Are you *creating* a settings file or using the settings file from the `My Project` tab?

Comment: @LarsTech, I created a settings file, not knowing there was already one associated with My Project. When I used that, I found it. Why not make this an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my comment, you don't have to create a new settings file, just use the Settings file that gets created when using the one from the `My Project` tab, and then the intellisense will show the property you are looking for.